# Different between -cacerts and -clcerts when using openssl

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my-certificate.pfx -out my-certificate.pem -cacerts

openssl pkcs12 -in my-certificate.pfx -out my-certificate.pem -clcerts
```

My understanding is that -c**a**cert will just contain the root certificate while -c**l**certs will include the complete certificate chain.  Is this correct?

I want to be able to extract the complete certificate chain from the pfx file, and Not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To extract complete certificate chain from pfx file use:

`openssl pkcs12 -in my-certificate.pfx -chain -nokeys -out my-certificate.pem`

Answer (score 2):

according to the documentation,

`-clcerts only output client certificates (not CA certificates).`

`-cacerts only output CA certificates (not client certificates).`

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/pkcs12.html